# Kivy using the StackLayout

Tags: kivy

I want to use a StackLayout but it only display one button and not two as I expected. The code is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import  Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


Builder.load_string("""

<ScreenUI>:
    orientation: 'lr-bt'
    Button:
        text: 'Button 1'
    Button:
        text: 'Button 2'

""")



class ScreenUI(StackLayout):
    pass

class WidgetApp(App): 

    def build(self):
        app = ScreenUI()
        return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WidgetApp().run()
```

How do I use a StackLayout and add a List of Button?

Update (to includes comments): To obtain the resize behaviour I used
    Builder.load_string("""

```
<ScreenUI>: 
    input1: input1
    button1: button1

    height: self.input1.height
    spacing: 5
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    id: layout1
    Label:
        text: 'Button 1'
        id: button1
        size: len(self.text) * root.input1.font_size, 2 * root.input1.font_size
        size_hint: None, None
    TextInput:
        id: input1
        text: 'Button 2'
        size: root.width - root.button1.width - root.spacing, 2 * self.font_size
        size_hint: None, None
""")
```

Does a more elegant method exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a size_hint problem. The buttons have no size specified, so the StackLayout automatically sizes them with their size hints. However, its layout doesn't depend on any sensible way of doing that, so it just makes them 100% of its own size...meaning only one fits in the window. That's the one you see.

Here's a slightly modified version of your example where sizes are specified. It works fine for me, with two differently sized buttons placed in the bottom left:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import  Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string("""
<ScreenUI>:
    orientation: 'lr-bt'
    Button:
        text: 'Button 1'
        size: 100, 100
        size_hint: None, None
    Button:
        text: 'Button 2'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 200, 100""")

class ScreenUI(StackLayout):
    pass

class WidgetApp(App):

    def build(self):
        app = ScreenUI()
        return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WidgetApp().run()
```

In general, the way to fix this is to give them a sensible size hint for whatever your particular goal is, or to set their sizes manually as I did. If you want a certain number to be sized properly to fill a space or similar, a GridLayout or BoxLayout may be more suitable.

Comment: What will the best layout to use,if I want a fixed height for the two buttons, but variable width for 'button 2' and fixed width for 'button 1'? I can't get StackLayout to do what I want to do.

Comment: I think I would subclass BoxLayout and set the width of Button 1 manually, then change the boxlayout width to change the width of button 2. It would depend on exactly what I wanted though, I don't know your use case.